# Pull requesting to a branch and merge branches

Tags: git, github

I have created a [test](https://github.com/mahmoodn/test) repository on Github and have forked a branch (dev) with another account. With the second account, I created a pull request and merged the changes in the dev branch. As you can see in the [repo](https://github.com/mahmoodn/test/pull/1) page, the changes are committed in the dev branch.

With my first account (repository holder), when I switch to dev branch, I don't see the modification.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mahmoodn/test
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 10, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), 2.13 KiB | 2.13 MiB/s, done.
$ git checkout -b dev
Switched to a new branch 'dev'
$ cat t.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
        return 0;
}
```

So, that means the commit and pull request have not fully been merged into the branch. Is that correct? Also I want to merge the dev changes into the main branch with my first account. How can I fix these issues?

Comment: You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ as you seem to be a Git beginner and some of your assumptions seem to be incorrect (you are using a lot of terms incorrectly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this command:

```
$ git checkout -b dev
```

What you did is to create a *new and different* `dev` branch based off of `main`. Hence what you are seeing is simply the `main` version of this file.

The remote `dev` branch from GitHub is represented on your machine by `origin/dev`. So what you wanted to do was to create a `dev` branch off of `origin/dev`.

So first delete this incorrect branch:

```
git branch -D dev
```

Then create the branch correctly:

```
git checkout --track origin/dev
```

That will create a local `dev` branch based on the remote `dev` branch and associate them. Actually you could say `switch` instead of `checkout` but it doesn't matter which you use.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, there are two branches in a local repository.

1. Local branches
2. Remote Branches

Whenever you clone a repository, git *downloads* the branches under *remote branches*. So you get the following branches after cloning

1. `origin/master`
2. `origin/dev`

These are your remote branches and you cannot commit on these.
In the mean time, git is also smart enough to create a local `master` whenever  you clone a remote repository. This is the branch where you can commit your changes. So your local branch by default is :

1. `master`

Now when you did `git branch -b dev` , git actually made a `dev` branch out of your current `master` and did not use `origin/dev`(which had your merged PR). You need to explicitly state to git that you need a local `dev` branch that tracks `origin/dev`.

The command you should have used is :

```
git branch -b dev --track origin/dev
```

Also, if you want this behaviour by default (where if you try to create a branch that also happens to have a same name as a remote branch, then git will automatically track it) then you can change your global git config by the following command :

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge always
```